# Parsing HTML elements by id and class with XML package

Tags: r, html-parsing

Is it possible to extract elements from an `HTMLInternalDocument` object by their `id` and `class` information?  For instance lets take a document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>R XML test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="obj1">
    <p id="txt1">quidquid</p>
    <p id="txt2">Latine dictum</p>
</div>
<div class="mystuff">
    <p>sit altum</p>
    <p>videtur</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And read into R as follows:

```
require(XML)
file <- "C:/filepath/index.html"
datain <- htmlTreeParse(readLines(file), useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

I'd like to extract the content of elements `id='txt2'` and `class='mystuff'`.

I've tried various methods without success, and they all seem to iterate down the tree which is painfully laborious.  Is there a shortcut method using class/id?  I have an idea it might involve using first `getNodeSet` followed by some apply method (e.g. `xmlApply` & `xmlAttrs`), but nothing I've tried works. Grateful for any pointers.

Comment: What "content" do you mean, the text? Try `cat(sapply(datain['//*[@id = "txt2"] | //*[@class = "mystuff"]'], xmlValue))`.

Comment: That looks rather promising. Forgive my ignorance but I haven't seen this formulation before `datain['//*[@id = "txt2"]']`  Is it an XML library method?

Comment: For details, have a look at the help under `?getNodeSet`: `getNodeSet(datain, '//*[@id = "txt2"]')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this for example :

```
id_or_class_xp <- "//p[@id='txt2']//text() | //div[@class='mystuff']//text()"
xpathSApply( doc,id_or_class_xp,xmlValue)

[1] "Latine dictum" "\n    "        "sit altum"     "\n    "        "videtur"       "\n"
```

where doc is:

```
doc <- htmlParse('<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>R XML test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="obj1">
    <p id="txt1">quidquid</p>
    <p id="txt2">Latine dictum</p>
</div>
<div class="mystuff">
    <p>sit altum</p>
    <p>videtur</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>',asText=T)
```